# Zip Code Search Rails 3 application recommendations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone have any good recommendations for zip code search in rails? I have looked at: http://zipcodesearch.rubyforge.org/, but it seems a little old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Geokit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/)

> **What can Geokit do for you?**
>
> - Distance calculations between two    points on the earth.
> - Calculate the    distance in miles or KM, with all the    trigonometry
>     abstracted away by    Geokit.
> - ActiveRecord distance-based    finders. For example, you can find
>     all the points in your database
>     within a 50-mile radius.
> - Geocoding    from multiple providers. It supports    Google,
>     Yahoo, Geocoder.us, Geonames,
>     Geocoder.ca, and more.
> - Geokit    provides a uniform response structure    from all of
>     them. It also provides a    fail-over
>     mechanism, in case your    input fails
>     to geocode in one    service.
> - IP-based location lookup    utilizing hostip.info. Provide an IP
>     address, and get city name and
>     latitude/longitude in return.
> - A    before_filter helper to geocode the    user's location based
>     on IP address,    and retain the
>     location in a cookie.

Comment: this only works with rails 2, do you know anything that works with rails 3?

Comment: https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3/ This is work in progress. But if you are only going to be using it for zip lookup, you might want to give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

[Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/geosearching.html) can search based on latitude/longitude.